# Creating multiple infoboxes and markers in google maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

Hey guys  I'm creating a map that uses multiple markers with a distinct infobox for each marker. I know I can use arrays to create the new markers but I don't know how I could make a unique infobox for each marker.

```
<code>
<html>
<head>
<title>Google Maps Test</title>
<style type="text/css">
#map_container{
    width:100%;
    height:350px;
}
#hook {
    color:#0C6;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" 
   src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function loadMap() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(4.3695030, 101.1224120);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 12,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_container"),myOptions);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latlng, 
      map: map, 
      title:"test"
    }); 
     var infoWindowOptions = {
    content: '<p id="hook">Hello World!</p>'
};

var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(infoWindowOptions);
google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click',function(e){

  infoWindow.open(map, marker);

});

  }

</script>
</head>

<body onLoad="loadMap()">
<div id="map_container"></div>
</body>

</html>
</code>
```

Comment: Some code to start with would be great

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use this one with infobox example: http://jsfiddle.net/ccJ9p/7/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/src/infobox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() {
    var secheltLoc = new google.maps.LatLng(49.47216, -123.76307),
         markers,
            myMapOptions = {
             zoom: 13,
            center: secheltLoc,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        },
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myMapOptions);

    function initMarkers(map, markerData) {
        var newMarkers = [],
            marker;

        for(var i=0; i<markerData.length; i++) {
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                draggable: true,
                position: markerData[i].latLng,
                visible: true
            }),
            boxText = document.createElement("div"),
            //these are the options for all infoboxes
            infoboxOptions = {
                 content: boxText,
                disableAutoPan: false,
                maxWidth: 0,
                pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-140, 0),
                zIndex: null,
                boxStyle: {
                    background: "url('http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/examples/tipbox.gif') no-repeat",
                    opacity: 0.75,
                    width: "280px"
                },
                closeBoxMargin: "12px 4px 2px 2px",
                closeBoxURL: "http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/close.gif",
                infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1),
                isHidden: false,
                pane: "floatPane",
                enableEventPropagation: false
            };

            newMarkers.push(marker);
            //define the text and style for all infoboxes
            boxText.style.cssText = "border: 1px solid black; margin-top: 8px; background:#333; color:#FFF; font-family:Arial; font-size:12px; padding: 5px; border-radius:6px; -webkit-border-radius:6px; -moz-border-radius:6px;";
            boxText.innerHTML = markerData[i].address + "<br>" + markerData[i].state;
            //Define the infobox
            newMarkers[i].infobox = new InfoBox(infoboxOptions);
            //Open box when page is loaded
            newMarkers[i].infobox.open(map, marker);
            //Add event listen, so infobox for marker is opened when user clicks on it.  Notice the return inside the anonymous function - this creates
            //a closure, thereby saving the state of the loop variable i for the new marker.  If we did not return the value from the inner function, 
            //the variable i in the anonymous function would always refer to the last i used, i.e., the last infobox. This pattern (or something that
            //serves the same purpose) is often needed when setting function callbacks inside a for-loop.
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                return function() {
                    newMarkers[i].infobox.open(map, this);
                    map.panTo(markerData[i].latLng);
                }
            })(marker, i));
        }

        return newMarkers;
    }

    //here the call to initMarkers() is made with the necessary data for each marker.  All markers are then returned as an array into the markers variable
    markers = initMarkers(map, [
        { latLng: new google.maps.LatLng(49.47216, -123.76307), address: "Address 1", state: "State 1" },
        { latLng: new google.maps.LatLng(49.47420, -123.75703), address: "Address 2", state: "State 2" },
        { latLng: new google.maps.LatLng(49.47530, -123.78040), address: "Address 3", state: "State 3" }
    ]);
}
</script>
<title>Creating and Using an InfoBox</title>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()" style="padding:1em">
<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 100%;-webkit-border-radius: 5px;-moz-border-radius: 5px;border-radius: 5px; height: 300px;border:1px solid #666;margin-bottom:1em;box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #333;"></div>
<p> This example shows the use of an InfoBox as a replacement for an InfoWindow.
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    if($.browser.msie) {
        $("<div/>", {html:"<br>Download Firefox <a href='http://www.mozilla.org/de/firefox/new/'>here</a>.", target:"_blank"}).appendTo("body");
    }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would love to! But I didn't ask the original question so I can't accept it. I actually flagged it and asked the mods to accept your answer, since your code is good and answers the OP's question (and solves the same problem I was having :-)...

Comment: @vtokmak thanks for this answer. I have implemented this code and its works. But it opens the infowindow for every marker, I want to open a infowindow when you click on that marker and previouly opened window should be close, how can i achieve this ?

Comment: Downvoted - doesn't work. (Click the marker and nothing shows up.)